# Process builder is not firing based on approval process field update

Tags: apex, soql, community, approval-process

I stuck in a place where in approval process i have a field update.

So based on this field value i run a process builder.But approval process is working fine.But the process builder is not working.If i edit the record after approved.It's working fine.Even i check the check box "REevaluate workflows" in that field update.

So,is there any restriction is there for this

Comment: Can you provide more details - e.g. process criteria logic?

Answer (score 3):

According to [Process order for automation rules and Apex triggers](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000005694&language=en_US) Knowledge Article:

> Workflow field updates that run based on an approval process or time-dependent action don't trigger any rules.